# Error Funciones PHP

Tags: php

Realizando un ejercico para practicar el paso de array a funciones php me he encontrado con el siguiente problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
                <?php

                //Array con los carácteres del abecedario
                $abecedary = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','Ñ','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
                //Array con los carácteres a comparar
                $input = array("H","O","L","A","M","U","N","D","O");
                //Vector con los códigos ASCII
                $collectionOfNumbers = array();
                $total = 0;

                function primeraFuncion (array $collecionOfNumbers, array $abecedary, array $input){
                    for($x = 0; $x < count($input); $x++ ){
                        for($y = 0; $y < count($abecedary); $y++){
                            if($input[$x] == $abecedary[$y]){ $collectionOfNumbers[$x] = $y +1; }
                        }
                    }    
                }

                function segundaFuncion (array $collectionOfNumbers){
                    foreach ($collectionOfNumbers as $value) {
                        $total += $value;
                        echo $value;
                    }
                    unset($value);
                    echo $total;
                }

                segundaFuncion(primeraFuncion($collectionOfNumbers,$abecedary,$input));

            ?>
```

No sé si el problema reside en el paso de arrays en la función, a la hora de hacer las llamadas o la manera en que tengo anidadas las funciones.

Comment: Le estas pasando a `segundaFuncion` como parámetro el valor que retorna `primeraFuncion`, el problema es que `primeraFuncion` no esta devolviendo ningún arreglo.

Comment: haciendo `return $collecionOfNumbers` el error se soluciona, ahora solo queda resolver que me imprime por pantalla 0. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Mire un poco el código, aunque realmente no tengo clara la funcionalidad logre hacer que funcione, lo que no me queda claro es que valor se espera de salida

```
<?php

//Array con los carácteres del abecedario
$abecedary = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'Ñ', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z');
//Array con los carácteres a comparar
$input = array('H', 'O', 'L', 'A', 'M', 'U', 'N', 'D', 'O');
//Vector con los códigos ASCII
$collectionOfNumbers = array();
$total = 0;

function primeraFuncion(array $collecionOfNumbers, array $abecedary, array $input)
{
    global $collectionOfNumbers;
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($input); ++$x) {
        for ($y = 0; $y < count($abecedary); ++$y) {
            if ($input[$x] == $abecedary[$y]) {
                $collectionOfNumbers[$x] = $y + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return $collectionOfNumbers;
}

function segundaFuncion(array $collectionOfNumbers)
{
    global $total;
    foreach ($collectionOfNumbers as $value) {
        $total += $value;
        echo $value;
    }
    unset($value);
    echo $total;
}

segundaFuncion(primeraFuncion($collectionOfNumbers, $abecedary, $input));

print_r($collectionOfNumbers);
?>
```

Comment: Se supone que se ha de imprimir las posición de cada carácter contenido en el array `input` y depués de obtener el resultado de todos ellos, sumarlo. Yo tampoco le encuntro el sentido pero como digo, es un ejercicio de práctica que me han mandado.

Comment: Mi problema ahora mismo es que `$collectionOfNumbers` no se está rellenando con ningún valor.

Comment: Al parecer funciona, prueba el código e intenta validar el resultado.

Comment: Por ahora no da error, pero tengo el problema que acabo de mencionar,

Comment: Tu resultado es correcto, he intendado cambiar mi código en base al que me has expuesto pero me devuelve 0 como valor. Interaré fijarme con más atención a ver si encuentro el error. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: En cuanto cuanto a la escritura del código, es poco elegante o se realiza mal algún paso de variables a las funciones? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Ya lo encontré, el problemas es que no estas definiendo las variables dentro de la función como global ya que se declararon fuera de ese contexto, he actualizado el código, intenta probar ahora.

Comment: Tal vez esto te ayude a entender mejor https://desarrolloweb.com/faq/505.php